# JQuery Flyup effect while opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to create a flyup for a block on hover similar to the one in the following link...

http://p2power.com/

Its just below the slide show... How do i create the exact effect using jquery?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried slideUp() function, but nothing happened. then i learnt that it hides everything rather than displaying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic example. You could do all this with CSS3 now, but here's the jQuery way.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: 200
    });
},function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: 0
    });        
});
```

You can test the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/effu/qW4DY/).

That should do it!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Depends what you are willing to sacrifice. If you don't mind loosing animations it would be a lot quicker/easier/faster in CSS3. That said, do some feature detection and just apply the jQuery if transitions aren't supported.

Comment: i dont no why, but your code is not working will. Can you suggest any widget that does this?

Comment: Take a look at Perception's jSfiddle he added. I didn't have time to do one myself, he's fixed a few errors as well: http://jsfiddle.net/effu/qW4DY/

Comment: ya i tried that. hover() function is not working atall when i copied the code for test. Any suggestions?